# Mysql PHP Header Problems

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently studying databases and php and am having considerable trouble.
Hope you guys can help.. ok the problem

I have 3 tables created in Mysql, Admin(Using PHPADMIN, on Mac) 
I have created 3 separate html forms to enter information into these tables.

When I hit submit, I need the information to be redirected and displayed on a separate .php/html page.  The problem im having is that the information is being entered correctly into the tables and it redirects me to the profile page fine the FIRST time. 
When I go back and make another entry into the same form (with different information) and hit submit it takes me to the profile page, but loading the same information from the first entry.  No matter how many times I try reentering information it keeps loading the first entry.
All the information I enter is going into the tables correctly.

Heres is the code for the Submit

```
 **<?php
        require 'connect_mysql.php';

        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
        ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);


        $SalesmanID = trim($_REQUEST['SalesmanID']);
        $password = trim($_REQUEST['password']);
        $FirstName = trim($_REQUEST['FirstName']);
        $LastName = trim($_REQUEST['LastName']);
        $Phone = trim($_REQUEST['Phone']);
        $Email = trim($_REQUEST['Email']);
        $DateAdded = trim($_REQUEST['DateAdded']);



         // Handle user request
         $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO Salesman (SalesmanID, password, FirstName,   LastName, Phone, Email, DateAdded) " .
                       "VALUES ('{$SalesmanID}','{$password}', '{$FirstName}', '{$LastName}', '{$Phone}', '{$Email}','{$DateAdded}') ; " ;

// Insert the user into the database
         mysql_query($insert_sql)
           or die(mysql_error());

// Redirect the user to the page that displays user information
    header("Location:../staff/salesmen/salesmen_profile_page.php?SalesmanID=" . mysql_insert_id());
    exit();
    ?>**
```

And here is the code on the Redirect Page

```
  **<?php

    require '../../scripts/connect_mysql.php';

        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
        ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

    // Get the user ID of the user to show
    $SalesmanID = $_REQUEST['SalesmanID'];

    // Build the SELECT statement
    $select_query = "SELECT * FROM Salesman WHERE SalesmanID = " . $SalesmanID;

    // Run the query
    $result = mysql_query($select_query);
    if ($result) {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $SalesmanID = $row['SalesmanID'];
        $FirstName = $row['FirstName'];
        $LastName = $row['LastName'];
        $Phone = $row['Phone'];
        $Email = $row['Email'];

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        }



    } else {
      die("Error locating user with ID {$SalesmanID}");
    }

    ?>**
```

The error warning shows nothing.

PLEASE HELP!
Thanks

Comment: First of all, stop using the `mysql_` methods - they've been deprecated for years and have big flaws. Use PDO or MySQLi. Secondly, your code is incredibly open to SQL injection so it won't be hard to hack, and anything including the character `'` will screw up your database call. Use prepared statements and bind variables. Thirdly, don't store passwords in cleartext. Hash them (preferebly with the bcrypt function `password_hash`)

Comment: Echo out your select statement and make sure it is correct by running it through phpmyadmin

Comment: Unfortunately, the course im currently in is using Mysql and all the information and books they want us to study is using this old method.. 
I wouldnt know where to start using Mysqli.

Comment: @StevenMihelakis Then at the very least use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: thanks all for the suggestions, couldnt get anything to work, 
til i went back through the book and restarted it from scratch. Realised I needed to make  a different Primary Key (eg UserID) and have it AutoIncrement instead of being included as field in the form...
All working good now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error has been suppress... try omitting the error_reporting and try again to see if there's any error.

Answer (score 0):

Steven,

You don't give us enough information, like HTTP method (POST/GET), webserver, source code of the forms, etc ...

Though, using what you gave, my best bet would be that your 302 Redirect is somehow cached and you always get redirected to the same `../staff/salesmen/salesmen_profile_page.php?SalesmanID=$ID` page.

This could be due to a proxy/cache server in front of your webserver, a misconfiguration of the webserver, the cache headers, the extensions used, etc ...

Comment: the method is POST, and im using localhost server MAMP

Comment: As explained in my answer and confirmed by your last comment (302 Found), you're hitting a **cache** (navigator) problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your server is redirectict with status `301 moved permanently`, check it out in devtools of your browser. If so, you may want to try setting additional header: `302 found` or `307 Temporary Redirect`.

Comment: when i hit submit it says in the dev tools, 302 Found,